# How can I call a load the Sinatra erb template view results into a variable? Is there a render_to_string equivalent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, view, erb

In Rails I can use:

```
x = ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string( 
            template: "my_module/my_view_template", 
            locals: { my_var: in_my_var})
```

This loads the view template results to a variable in Rails.
How can I do this in Sinatra?

I'm open to any templating language but I prefer Erubis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sinatra Template Doc: [Link](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates)

erb is a function that returns a string. You can just assign it to a variable

```
get '/' do
  template_output = erb :template
  "Here is the output from template: #{template_output}"
end
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!